# How to group multiple values into one based on specific column value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress-rest-api

I'm working on my project and I need some help. I'm making my custom endpoint in WordPress. Everything works fine except one thing. I have database:

| id | city | company | email | website |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | city_1 | company one | comp@example.com | comp1.com |
| 12 | city_2 | company two | comp2@example.com | comp2.com |
| 31 | city_2 | company three | comp3@example.com | comp3.com |
| 72 | city_3 | company four | comp4@example.com | comp4.com |

I want to print JSON which contains that format

```
   {
      "city":"city_1",
      "companies": [
        {
         "id":"22",
         "email":"comp@example.com",
         "website":"comp1.com"
        }
      ],
   },
   {
      "city":"city_2",
      "companies": [
        {
         "id":"12",
         "email":"comp2@example.com",
         "website":"comp2.com"
        },
        {
         "id":"31",
         "email":"comp3@example.com",
         "website":"comp3.com"
        }
      ],
   },
   {
      "city":"city_4",
      "companies": [
        {
         "id":"72",
         "email":"comp4@example.com",
         "website":"comp4.com"
        }
      ],
   },
```

So, I want to group multiple values into one based on city value. How Can I do it? I tried with GROUP BY statement but it gives me one row.
My current SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM database ORDER BY city COLLATE utf8_polish_ci
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

> JSON_ARRAYAGG

```
select JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('city',city,'companies',companies)) from (
select city,JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id',id,'company', 
company,'email',email,'website',website)) as companies from test group by city
)t;
```

This will print the expected output in JSON format.

Output:

```
[
{
"city": "city_1", "companies": [{"id": 22, "email": "comp@example.com ", "company": "company one  ", "website": "comp1.com"}]
}, 
{
"city": "city_2", "companies": [{"id": 12, "email": "comp2@example.com", "company": "company two  ", "website": "comp2.com"}, 
{"id": 31, "email": "comp3@example.com", "company": "company three", "website": "comp3.com"}]
}
]
```

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thank you so much! I have one more thing. The output that I have is a one huge string
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#8002 (1) {
    ["JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('city',city,'companies',companies))"]=>
    string(32687) "

I want to use this JSON in Javascript so my questions is. How can I change it to correct format JSON, not a string?

Comment: You can use json-decode to convert JSON string to JSON object. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php